# inserir multiplos dados no mysql com while

Tags: mysql

Boa noite galera!

criei esse código com o objetivo de inserir 5 novos usuários e senhas que seguem um padrão `PAM1` ... `PAM5` e `CP@M20161` ... `CP@M20165`,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myfunction()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE i < 6 DO
    INSERT INTO teste (userlogin, userpass) VALUES ("PAM" + i, MD5 ("CP@M2016" + i));
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

não está dando erro de sintaxe, mas diz que a procedure já existe...
como resolver esse problema, pois o procedimento será feito para 4000 `inserts` depois que fizer funcionar...
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!

Comment: Delete a anterior antes de inserir uma com o mesmo nome. Uma possível melhoria seria você pegar o i da autonumeração (ou do maior ID já existente), e usar um parâmetro para dizer quantas inserções, assim bastaria chamar a função sempre que quiser adicionar mais N usuários (isso se for precisar novamente desta procedure no futuro, claro)

Comment: o problema é que não há outra... só há essa...